# How do I abstractly work with theorems and terms using locale assumptions and variables in ML?

Tags: isabelle

Consider the following locale definition:

```
locale my_locale =
  fixes a :: nat
  assumes "a > 0"
begin

definition "f n ≡ a + n"
lemma f_pos: "f x > 0"
  sorry

end
```

In Isar, if I attempt to work with the definition of `f` or the lemma `f_pos`, the locale assumptions and fixed variables are hidden from me. For example, `thm f_def f_pos` returns:

```
f ?n ≡ a + ?n
0 < f ?x
```

as expected.

If, however, I try to reason about these terms in ML, the "hidden" fixed variables are suddenly exposed. `ML {* @{thm f_def} |> prop_of *}`, for instance, returns:

```
Const ("==", "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ prop") $
 (Const ("TestSimple.my_locale.f", "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat") $
   Free ("a", "nat") $ Var (("n", 0), "nat")) $
 (Const ("Groups.plus_class.plus", "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat") $
   Free ("a", "nat") $ Var (("n", 0), "nat"))
```

where the fixed variable `a` becomes a parameter to the function `f`.

Is there a way to be able to work inside a locales in ML so that I am not exposed to such locale variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the version of `f` which doesn't have the parameter `a` is simply an abbreviation generated by the `locale` command. In particular, typing `print_abbrevs` shows:

```
local.f ≡ My_Theory.my_locale.f a
```

This means that from the user's perspective, `f` doesn't appear to have any locale parameters, as they are hidden behind the abbreviation. Behind the scenes, however, `f` will always have the locale parameter attached to it, and thus ML code must be coded to explicitly handle it.